# ADMINISTRADOR CUENTA GRIS DESAPARECIDO

Tags: html

Tengo una cuenta de empresa en FB administrada por una cuenta gris que abrió una publicista hace 10 años actualmente en paradero desconocido. Al recibrir notificacion de la eliminacion de esta cuenta gris por FB, primero abrí una cuenta FB nueva para administrar mi página de empresa y desligé al administrador para ponerme como administradora a través de la nueva cuenta de FB.
SORPRESA!!, al desligar la cuenta de empresa de la cuenta gris, no puedo acceder a la cuenta de empresa que se abrío con correo y contraseña que no tengo.
como recupero mi página de empresa??? Pro favor, necesito respuesta porque estoy perdida totalmente

Comment: Este sitio es sobre preguntas acerca de _programación_... Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de lo definido en las guías de [ask]

Comment: **como recupero mi página de empresa?** Pues supongo que poniéndote en contacto con FB, ¿no?. ¿Qué pintamos nosotros allí?